# swift 5 Как создать интерфейс предложения, который подойдет для всех версий iOS?

Tags: swift, xcode

На разных версиях iOS виджеты меняют свое местоположение в main.storyboard Это както регулируется автоматически, и когда я запущу предложение на iPhone, то все будет нормально, или мне придется создавать виджеты через константы? Не нашел в интернете

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Изучите тему [Autolayout](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/index.html) и [Size Classes](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Size-ClassSpecificLayout.html) для понимания принципов верстки интерфейсов в зависимости от устройства, можете найти дальнейшую информацию самостоятельно по этим ключевым словам, ее достаточно